# why is the answer not showing up?

Tags: c++, function, user-defined-functions

I am doing a code in c++ where I am supposed to be finding the series and I build the function for the series myself yet and I call the function I don't find my answer
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double harmonicSeries(int n);
int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter n" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    harmonicSeries(n);
}
double harmonicSeries(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        float s;
        float sum = 0.0;
        s = 1 / n;
        sum += s;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

I will be thankful for any help

Comment: You forgot to print the result of your function, try `std::cout << harmonicSeries(n);`

Comment: Also, your function always returns after the first loop iteration, are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: I fixed it a bit according to your comments but now i am getting the wrong answer

Comment: ```#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double harmonicSeries(int n);
int main() {
    double n;
    cout << "Enter n" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout<<harmonicSeries(n);
}
double harmonicSeries(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        double s;
        double sum = 0.0;
        s = 1 / n;
        sum += s;
    }
    double sum{};
        return sum;
} ```

Answer (score 0):

See I have made the changes in your code,this works fine in this finding numbers and adding to get their sum.You should use return outside the function and basically harmonic series is of form 1/n which can be  any float number or double number so I use **s** as double and i has float(which by this).

**s=1/i(double=1/float,gets converted to double)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double harmonicSeries(int n);
int main() {
int n;
cout << "Enter n" << endl;
cin >> n;
cout<<harmonicSeries(n);
 }
double harmonicSeries(int n) {
double sum=0.00;
double s;
for (float i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    s = 1 / i;
    sum += s;
}
return sum;
}
```

If you find anything wrong do ask for sure:)

Comment: oh, i just realized my mistake so really really thank you

Comment: No worries.Always to help:)